# Project 'HelloFacebookSample' is missing required Java project 'facebook'

Tags: android, facebook

I have been following [the instructions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/) for integrating the facebook SDK into my apps. I have succeeded in getting all the given sample apps to compile and run except for "helloFacebookSample". For this I get a compilation error:

```
Project 'HelloFacebookSample' is missing required Java project 'facebook'
```

My understanding of projects/libraries/build paths etc is a little hazy, but I can not work out why this should fail where all the others succeeded.

Here's a screen grab of my properties window for HelloFacebookSample:
[image]

I can confirm that the directory:

```
c:\android stuff\facebook\facebook-android-sdk-3.0\facebook\bin
```

contains a file facebooksdk.jar

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Thrashing around some more, I just clicked on the "projects" tab that you see in the screen grab above, and saw that it says "facebook (missing)". I'm a bit confused because I thought that projects may need to rely on *libraries* rather than other projects... but still I have no idea how to resolve the problem. I don't seem to have a project called simply "facebook"...

**Edit:** thrashing around some more, I just experimentally deleted the "facebook (missing)" from the java build path and then did an "add" of "FacebookSDK"... I thought this was cluttching at straws, but to my surprise it worked!!! HelloFacebookSample compiled and ran!!! - I have no idea what's going on though and would still like an explanation.

Comment: Could it be anything to with what android api you're building against? I seem to remember having to lower the target api a little...

Comment: have you selected checkbox "copy projects in the workspace" at  the time of importing all of the component projects from facebook-sdk-3.0?

Comment: @kaushai trivedi: I make sure that "copy projects in the workspace" was *not* selected (as the website instructed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous version of the Android Facebook SDK referred to the project as 'facebook'.  It looks like this sample was not updated to delete the old reference, and add the new one to 'FacebookSDK'.  You took the corrective steps to resolve this yourself already by modifying the Java Build Path of the project.

Answer (score 0):

The problem will easily be removed by simply going to the properties of your project and right clicking it, then go to project tab, select the project which prompts missing and remove it.

Now click on `project->build project->clean`

Now run your project and it will surely do fine